# New file created inside Django App to seed data

Tags: django, pandas, seed

I've created an application inside my django project called SeedData. I've added then a file called import_data.py where I will be reading csv files and adding them to my database.

```
-SeedData
--__pycache__
--migrations
--__init__.py
--admin.py
--apps.py
--import_data.py
-- etc..
```

But whenever i do the following:

```
from Product.models import Product
from Category.models import Category
from SubCategory.models import SubCategory
from Brand.models import Brand
import pandas as pd
```

I get this error

```
File "C:\Users\...\SeedData\import_data.py", line 9, in <module>
    from Product.models import Product
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Product'
```

It's the same for Category, SubCategory and Brand.
I'd also like to say that the project is fully functional and all the mentioned projects above works perfectly fine.

Comment: Is there a django app named `Products`? (It's conventional to use lowercase names for modules). How are you running `import_data.py`? Custom commands or scripts using django models should usually be implemented as django management commands. This will ensure that database operations etc. work properly. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: Yes there is an app called Product. Also, I'm running import_data from the terminal. I'll check dmc right now thank you.

Comment: If you are running it from the SeedData directory, the import probably fails because the django project root is not in sys.path. Using a management command will fix that. Your project root will be sys.path if you run the command using the project root as working directory `python manage.py my_command`. Alternatively you can add the project root directory to PYTHONPATH, for example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525117/how-do-i-add-my-project-to-sys-path-on-windows-trying-to-use-disqus-export-p This lets you use `django-admin my_command` from any working directory.

Comment: So I moved my script to this command feature django allows us to do. I'm now able to read files and import them. Thank you a ton buddy!